# pandas datetime not finding max time correctly

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, datetime, max

I have data from SQL server.  I've converted these to pandas datetime like so:
`pd.to_datetime(max(df2[endTime]), format='%H:%M:%S %p')` However it is not working correctly to get the maximum time of the series.  Does anyone know why?

As you can see, index 100 is the maximum time, but it is giving me index 763.

[image: date problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign it back

```
s=pd.to_datetime(s,format='%H:%M:%S %p').dt.time
s.max()
Out[1294]: datetime.time(10, 9, 57)
```

Data Input

```
s=pd.Series(['10:09:57 AM','9:59:55 AM'])
```

Update

```
s=pd.Series(['10:09:57 AM','9:59:55 AM'])
s=pd.to_datetime(s,format='%H:%M:%S %p')

s-s.max()
Out[1313]: 
0            00:00:00
1   -1 days +23:49:58
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Cool.  This did work, but I am now unable to subtract the times.  I need to do the max time minus the min time.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @JuliaDills see the update , datetime.time no support '-'

Comment: very sorry! @Wen - you are awesome. i didn't get the update in time.  for the record, this also works:`duration = datetime.combine(date.min, end) - datetime.combine(date.min, start)` BUT you have to import two things:`import datetime
from datetime import datetime, date`

Comment: @JuliaDills no worry, happy coding : -)